# Out of memory errors on orientation change

Tags: android, memory-leaks, screen-orientation, osmdroid

I have an app which uses an osmdroid mapactivity.

Every time the screen orientation the heap size grows and after a couple of orientation changes I get the following errors:

```
12-12 00:53:08.990: E/dalvikvm-heap(6712): Out of memory on a 262160-byte allocation.
12-12 00:53:08.990: I/dalvikvm(6712): "filesystem" prio=5 tid=46 RUNNABLE
12-12 00:53:08.990: I/dalvikvm(6712):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x43057e08 self=0x571583c8
12-12 00:53:08.990: I/dalvikvm(6712):   | sysTid=8674 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1487255264
12-12 00:53:08.990: I/dalvikvm(6712):   | schedstat=( 298265664 165380214 301 ) utm=25 stm=4 core=0
12-12 00:53:08.990: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:449)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.BitmapTileSourceBase.getDrawable(BitmapTileSourceBase.java:93)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFilesystemProvider$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileFilesystemProvider.java:142)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleProviderBase.java:241)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-12 00:53:08.995: I/dalvikvm(6712):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-12 00:53:09.020: I/dalvikvm-heap(6712): Clamp target GC heap from 64.436MB to 64.000MB
12-12 00:53:09.050: I/dalvikvm-heap(6712): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 262160-byte allocation
12-12 00:53:09.095: I/dalvikvm-heap(6712): Clamp target GC heap from 64.436MB to 64.000MB
```

I have an Activity which holds two fragments and both of those fragments extend one abstract fragment which initialises the MapActivity.

I have read quite a few posts from other people with the same problem. I ended up implementing the following in the abstract Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        unbindDrawables(con.findViewById(R.id.main_layout));
        System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }
```

Here is my onCreateView which initialises con:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        con = container;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment,container, false);
    }
```

I am not sure what else I can do.

can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you loading some images in your app?

Comment: You have a memory leak in your application. Install MAT http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html and check which references are preventing the GC from collecting objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try handling the screen rotation yourself, add the following code into the activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and add the following into your activity tag in your manifest file

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: Read the doc, handling the orientation changes by yourself is the last possible solution you should do. So basically try everything else before you do that...

Comment: Hi, I did a memory analysis which basically revealed a large amount of space being used on byte[]. I drilled down further and there were a number of allocations for Bitmap objects.

I implemented your solution and it seems to work very well. I don't understand why though. Could you explain why adding that code avoids the memory errors?

Thanks

Comment: when the orientation changes, the activity is destroyed and recreated, and memory can leak. by overriding onConfigurationChanged, the activity is not recreated, you handle the change yourself

Answer (score 1):

Always let the OS handle your orientation changes!

Your activity will be recreated if there is a configuration change, e.g. orientation change. The cause of the most memory leaks is that there is some async operation which holds a (implicit/explicit) reference to your view, which prevents your view being garbage collected. For example if you use CountDownTimer or non-static inner runnable.